# Can you have Vim C completion with GCC YCM?

Tags: gcc, vim, clang, avr-gcc

I was wondering if it's possible to get autocompletion in Vim (perhaps using YCM) but when using GCC instead of Clang. I have a project where I am to implement machine intelligence for a drone to have it navigate around and map a room. We're therefore using avr-gcc and not Clang (there's a avr-clang but it's in early stages and is therefore not suitable for this project). Is there a way to get proper autocompletion in Vim where the editor would be able to detect variables from libraries I include? I know with Clang it's possible :)

Comment: Why do you think using GCC to compile your project would prevent Clang to find your libraries?

Comment: Because that's what I was told, so I don't know @romainl